# Как защитить агрегируемое поле таблицы базы данных от изменений из вне?

Tags: mysql, sql

В базе данных MySQL имеется таблица с постами `posts`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `count_comments` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

и таблица с комментариями `comments`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

столбец `posts.count_comments` содержит количество комментариев для конкретного поста.

Проблема в том, что программный интерфейс позволяет записать в `posts.count_comments` любое значение. Что бы выйти из ситуации, нашла не очень красивый хак, состоящий из следующих процедур и триггеров.

```
DELIMITER |

-- добавляем комментарий (на обновление и удаление аналогичные)
CREATE TRIGGER AfterInsertComment
    AFTER INSERT
    ON comments
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL ResetCommentCount(NEW.post_id);
END |

-- в процедуре указываем int`овому полу значение NULL, само поле NOT NULL,
-- это необходимо что бы распознать изменение как требуемое к перерасчёту
CREATE PROCEDURE ResetCommentCount(PostId INT)
BEGIN
    UPDATE posts SET count_comments = NULL WHERE id = PostId;
END |

-- триггер на изменение таблицы posts
-- условие NEW.count_comments IS NULL проверяет необходимость в пересчёте, устанавливается в процедуре ResetCommentCount,
-- условие NEW.count_comments != OLD.count_comments обрабатывает попытку изменения извне
CREATE TRIGGER BeforeUpdatePost
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON posts
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.count_comments IS NULL OR NEW.count_comments != OLD.count_comments THEN
        NEW.count_comments = (
            SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0)
            FROM comments
            WHERE s.post_id = NEW.id
        );
    END IF;
END |
```

Указывать в триггере `BeforeUpdatePost` условие, например, `NEW.count_comments < 0` не получится, т.к. выше приведён частный случай использования. Так же не получится без `NEW.count_comments IS NULL`, потому что мы не узнаем что необходимо пересчитать количество комментариев.

Есть более удачный вариант, что бы не позволить изменить поле `posts.count_comments` ни чем кроме средств движка MySQL?

Comment: А для чего такая защита ? Вы боитесь, что случайно укажете в коде внешнего приложения update этого поля ? Или собираетесь предоставлять доступ к БД на запись третьим лицам

Comment: Это учебный проект, мне не нравится появившаяся ситуация, поэтому хочется найти элегантное не пробиваемое решение.

Comment: Лично я не вижу в этой ситуации ничего от чего бы стоило защищаться. Если мы боимся что запишем в поле, которое в приложении даже не упоминается, то почему мы например не боимся что код случайно в title поста не запишет комментарий ? И если учебное задание, я бы вообще поля count_comments не делал. Оно как бы лишнее и может применяться только в случае появления проблем с производительностью (но проблемы с производительностью при вашем желании защититься от записи в поле и так гарантированы)

Comment: А вообще, когда хотят от такого защищаться, то вообще запрещают приложению писать в таблицу (на уровне прав доступа) и всю запись проводят только через хранимые процедуры, у которых просто не будет такого поля как количество в параметрах. Или через view